# Using a variable across two blocks

Tags: objective-c

I have added a method `-dct_asynchronousTaskWithWorkBlock:completionBlock:` to NSManagedObjectContext which runs the work block in another GCD queue and then runs the completion block on the main thread. The method does the following:

1. Creates a second managed object context to use in the other queue
2. Calls the work block with this new context
3. Saves and merges that context into itself
4. Calls the completion block with itself

This addition can be seen on [GitHub](http://github.com/danielctull/DCTCoreData/blob/master/Asynchronous/NSManagedObjectContext%2BDCTAsynchronousTasks.m).

My issue is that I create a new `User` managed object in the work block that I'd like to reference in the completion block. I thought the solution would be to create a reference to an object ID like so:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *objectID = nil;

[self.managedObjectContext dct_asynchronousTaskWithWorkBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc) {

    NSManagedObject *user = // create new user.

    objectID = [user objectID];

} completionBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc) {

    NSManagedObject *user = [moc objectWithID:objectID];

}];
```

I have also tried copying the blocks and in both cases I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the objectID in the completion block.

Is it possible to reference the user's objectID in the work block from the completion block? Or do I need to work in a way to handle passing the reference in the category method.

**Update:**

Luke was right about retaining across the block calls, as the user in the first is in a background thread and the user in the second is in main.

This is my fix at the moment:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *objectID = nil;

[self.managedObjectContext dct_asynchronousTaskWithWorkBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc) {

    NSManagedObject *user = // create new user.

    objectID = [user objectID];
    [objectID retain];

} completionBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc) {

    NSManagedObject *user = [moc objectWithID:objectID];
    [objectID release];

}];
```

I am now wondering whether this looks odd. Upon reading just this code you may ask if there could be a leak for example. I know that the category definitely calls the completion block regardless of what happens in the first block, but I don't know whether it looks obvious enough just from this piece of code.

Comment: What happens if you retain the objectID in the work block and release again in the completion block? Could objectID be being released (because the original user object has been released?) in between the block calls?

Comment: Yup, retaining objectID in the original and releasing in the completion worked. Not sure how I feel with that, as from this code it's not obvious that both blocks will get called - even though I know they will. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of your category is to keep your work and completion blocks clear of any code related to setup and teardown of the second MOC, you could return the completion block from the work block:

```
[self.managedObjectContext dct_asynchronousTask:^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc) {

    NSManagedObject *backgroundThreadUser = // create new user.
    NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [backgroundThreadUser objectID];

    return ^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc) {
        NSManagedObject *mainThreadUser = [moc objectWithID:objectID];
        // ...
    };
}];
```

Comment: Yep, I think this will work pretty well. Last night I was thinking of going down the route of having the work block returning an object that the method would pass into the completion block, which is a little eugh to me. This seems perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Luke is right, but...

Why have a work block and a completion block at all?

The GCD APIs originally looked like:

```
dispatch_async(q, workBlock, completionBlock);
```

But that proved to be silly.   A workBlock always knows when it is complete, so why not put the completion logic into workBlock?  Beyond making for a simpler API, it also eliminates any need to have an ethereal mechanism for transferring state from work block to completion block.

---

```
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    ... do heavy duty work on background here ...
    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
        ... merge into main queue context here ...
        ... update UI ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense -- simply use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* completion block */ }); at the end of the work block.

Comment: The trouble here is that the managed object context needs to merge back to the main context, which is handled by the category method - the reasoning behind this method is so that I'm not writing context merge code everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, hit return, then spent too long editing... The trouble here is that the managed object context needs to merge back to the main context before I can use any of the objects created in the background queue's context. This is handled by the category method in between calling the workBlock and completionBlock; The main reasoning behind this method is so that I'm not writing context merge code everywhere. This approach has worked well for all the other times, when I have an existing managed object that needs updating or a reference to an object that becomes related to the new objects.

Comment: Is there a reason why the merge method couldn't be called on the completion block?

Comment: No reason why it couldn't, of course. However, pretty much the only reason for this method's existence is to prevent me from having to write that merging code over and over again. :)

Comment: Not sure why it'd be more than a method call?

Comment: Our reasoning for doing something very similar is ensuring that there is ever only one write and read happening simultaneously with an NSOperationQueue. So inside a very large SDK, you don't end up with this issue: Someone grabs a temp context and starts doing some writing, but while that writing is happening, someone else grabs a context, writes, and merges, so that when the first context is finished writing and is merged, there are now merge conflicts.